# Alternative to Linked server, with same speed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server, sqlclr, openrowset

I have a framework build with stored procedures that moves data 1 to 1 fra an OLTP to a BI staging area. It is generic, just tell it which table in the OLTP, and it builds the sql to move it.

Problem is, it is build to use linked servers to the OLTP server.
Now the OLTP is starting to add CLR type columns like geography to the tables, which cannot be collected via Linked server.

I have been looking at `OPENROWSET`  to do the job instead, to keep the stored procedure solution and do minimal work

First i tried with tables without clr columns and found that using ODBC via 'MSDASQL' was 4 times slower than the linked server (allthough i was doing it with the latest odbc driver we had for sql server 2016)

If i used in my test environment

`OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=my server;Trusted_Connection=yes;' select ...)`

the speed was the same as linked server, but SQLNCLI is in fact using the linked server. 
And if i choose a table with CLR types, it failed as expected, so that is not a solution.

I know that if i start building the same generic setup in SSIS, i wont see these problems, but will take longer to develop. I could also setup replication, log shipping, or other new solutions, but before doing that i want to be sure that it cannot be done by changing the existing solution.

So before i start doing that, do you have any suggestions to how i get better throughput if all i want to change is the resulting tsql in my framework?(both the OLTP and the BI server are SQL Server 2016)

Very simplified, the current resulting tsql is this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM OLTP.BrokerServices.[FLEUR].[InsuredUnemploymentPayment]
```

where OLTP is the linked server.

And i want to end with something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
                'MSDASQL', 
                'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; Server=DFDGSQLCLU2003\SQL2016;UID=yyyyyyyyyyyy; PWD=xxxxxxxxxxx;',  
                'SELECT * FROM [BrokerServices].[FLEUR].[InsuredUnemploymentPayment]'
                )
```

The above works, but is at least 4 times slower than using the Linked server, and we do not have that much time.

TIA

Peter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternate to SQL Server Linked Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002968/alternate-to-sql-server-linked-server)

Answer (score 2):

I actually found the answer myself :-)
Using SQLOLEDB instead of MSDASQL, gave the performance i wanted, and can handle CLR datatypes:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
                'SQLOLEDB', 
                'STARDBS1006\T16';'yyyyyyyyyy';'xxxxxxxxxxx',  
                'SELECT * FROM [BrokerServices].[FLEUR].[InsuredUnemploymentPayment]'
                )
```

Sorry for that, but i will leave the question, just in case someone else has the same issue