# Alternate to SQL Server Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to build a program that compares 2 database servers that have exact table but in some table have additional column. I am using linked server to connect these 2 database servers.

But I found a problem, when I try to compare some data the connection is mostly timeout. And when I check Activity Monitor and Execution plan, more than 90% is in remote query - this makes comparing 1 record that has 5 child entries run for 5-7 minutes.

This is a sample query that I try to run.

```
Select 
    pol.PO_TXN_ID, pol.Pol_Num 
From 
    ServerA.InstanceA.dbo.POLine pol  
Where 
    not exist (Select 1 
               From ServerB.InstanceA.dbo.POLine pol2 
               where pol.PO_TXN_ID = pol2.PO_TXN_ID 
                 and pol.Pol_Num = pol2.Pol_Num)
```

I tried using `OPENROWSET`, but our administrator does not permit to install it on the production server.

Is there any alternative that I can use to optimize my query instead using linked server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options:

- OpenQuery() / 4 part naming with temp tables.
- ETL (eg: SQL Server Integration Services)

The problem with linked servers especially with 4 part naming like in your example:

- The query engine doesn't know how to optimize it. He can't access statistics on the linked servers
- Resulting in doing full table scans, pulling all the data to the source SQL server and then processing it. (High network IO, Bad execution plans, resulting in long running queries)

#### Option 1

1. Create a temp table (preferably with indexes)
2. Query the linked server with OPENQUERY and preferably a filter condition. eg:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable(Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, /*Other columns*/)
INSERT INTO #MyTempTable(Id, , /*Other columns*/)
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(ServerA, 'SELECT Id,  /*Other columns*/ FROM Table WHERE /*Condition*/')
```

3. Use the temp table(s) to do your calculation.

*Still needs at least 1 linked server*

*OPENQUERY has better performance when your database is not a SQL Server (e.g. Postgres, MySql, Oracle,...) as the query is executed on the linked server instead of pulling all the data to the source server.*

#### Option 2

You can use an ETL tool like SQL Server Integration Services ([SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver15))

- Load the data from the 2 servers
- Use a [Slowly changing dimension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/slowly-changing-dimension-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15) or [lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/lookup-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15) component to determine the differences.
- Insert/update what you want/need

*No linked servers are needed, SSIS can connect to the databases directly*

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i tried the openquery and it works faster than linked server

Comment: Please consider upvoting / accepting the answer if it solved your question.